# Testing URL Redirect Using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want test if a web site URL will redirect to secured site or not. For example, if I type `example.com` in the address bar, it should redirect to `https://example.com`.

From Selenium, I tried using both `get("")` and `navigate("")` with no luck. It shows an exception as wrong URL. How can I test this or proceed another way?

Even Javascript will not work.

Comment: Just do driver.get("www.example.com") and then use driver.getCurrentUrl() to check if it has moved to secure site... If you want to do this faster you can look at a plain java unit test using the URL and HttpUrlConnection classes - https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: corrected a typo.

Answer (score 5):

It's very easy to achieve this using `get()` & `getCurrentUrl()`. You should type the actual URL, like `www.example.com` instead of just using `example.com`. Even tough you type the URL without the `www`, the browser makes that change automatically but not Selenium, hence it throws an exception. Try something like this:

```
driver.get("www.example.com");

//add wait for page to load completely

if(driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("https"))
    System.out.println("Success");
else
    System.out.println("Failure");
```

Comment: But point here is i'm not suppose to pass www. . My input will be example.com . And test redirected URL  contains https

Comment: Well you can't do it that way. Selenium doesn't recognize `example.com` as a valid URL. It needs a fully valid URL which either starts with www or http(s)

Comment: @JayeshDoolani `example.com` _is_ a valid URL. My website, for instance, does _not_ work if you go to the `www` subdomain.

Comment: No www subdomain means that you'd still have to specify the protocol however. So http://example.com. you can test the https protocol was redirected

Comment: getCurrentUrl seems to be depricated